# generators and list of lambda functions: all functions are being overwritten by last one

Tags: python, list, lambda, generator, overwrite

I had written code where I passed a generator of lambda functions to a varargs function that iterates over the generator and applies the function to a container. But the result was not as expected. Only the last function was called. But `n` times, where `n` is the number of functions in the generator. Consider the following MWE:

```
>>> def f(*fs):
...     for f in fs:
...         print(f.__code__)
...         print(f(1))
... 
>>> f(*(lambda x : k*x for k in range(3)))
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca683130, file "<stdin>", line 1>
2
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca683130, file "<stdin>", line 1>
2
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca683130, file "<stdin>", line 1>
2
```

I next tested going over a list of lambdas without the function call and varargs part. Same result.

```
>>> for f in [lambda x : k*x for k in range(3)]:
...     print(f.__code__)
...     print(f(1))
... 
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca634b30, file "<stdin>", line 1>
2
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca634b30, file "<stdin>", line 1>
2
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca634b30, file "<stdin>", line 1>
2
```

Then I tested it with just a generator. The printing of `f.__code__` shows, that the function is redefined on the spot. It is always the same address but with different content. So the previous function gets overwritten each time the generator proceeds.

```
>>> for f in (lambda x : k*x for k in range(3)):
...     print(f.__code__)
...     print(f(1))
... 
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca683130, file "<stdin>", line 1>
0
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca683130, file "<stdin>", line 1>
1
<code object <lambda> at 0x7fe1ca683130, file "<stdin>", line 1>
2
```

Why is that and how can I pass a generator of lambdas to a function without ending up with `n` times the last function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python lambda's binding to local values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values) .. maybe not exactly a dupe but related

Comment: Also, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40685006/198633

Comment: Why do you claim default values don't solve this? `f(*(lambda x, k=k: k*x for k in range(3)))` does exactly what I'd expect. See https://sopython.com/canon/30/why-do-my-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions-created-in-a-loop-all-use-the-las/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah right, I did something wrong then.

Comment: The reason it works with the generator is that `k` only changes at the time that the next `f` is computed from the generator, and then it's used immediately.